# Is there any extension for vscode to make it support C intelligence only (without C++)?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clangd

Due to my job, I have to develop software with only C but not C++.
It will be good that when I write `class A {};` Vscode will display an error or a warning.
Now I use clangd, it will be great if some settings can satisfy.

Comment: Shouldn't Clangd detect the language from the file extension? Unless you override it in `compile_commands.json`.

Comment: You could specify in your compile_flags.txt (Or another configuration file for clangd) that you are strictly asking for C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clangd will correctly issue diagnostics for C++-only constructs, if it's parsing your file in C mode.

So it's a matter of making sure clangd is parsing your files in the correct language mode.

If your file's extension is unambiguously a C-language extension (for example, `.c`), then clang should parse the file in C mode automatically.

If the extension is ambiguous, like `.h`, then clangd attempts to choose the language heuristically, which can sometimes give a wrong answer. In this case, you can specify the language explicitly in the file's compile command, for example by adding `-x c-header` to specify "parse as a C header".

One way to do this is using `CompileFlags:` `Add:` in the [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html#add). For example, to specify that all `.h` files in the project are C headers, you might add the following to the project `.clangd` file:

```yaml
If:
  PathMatch: .*\.h

CompileFlags:
  Add: [-xc-header]
```